# JQuery: Can't removeClass when iterating (.each()) over list items using .on('click')

Tags: jquery, onclick, addclass, each, removeclass

I am using JQuery to iterate over a `ul` list, and by using the `.on('click'...)` I want to add a class to the currently clicked `li` while removing it from the previously selected `li`

jsFIDDLE here: [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/jremydeaton/S6mMF/1/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="divisionMenus">
    <ul>
        <li>Type 01</li>
        <li>Type 02</li>
        <li>Type 03</li>
        <li>Type 04</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<p class="results"></p>
```

**CSS:**

```
#divisionMenus {
    width: 220px;
    min-height: 220px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 5px;
    background-color: #003399;
}
#divisionMenus ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#divisionMenus ul li {
    padding: 18px;
    border-top: 3px solid #111;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#divisionMenus ul li:hover {
    background-color: #c0dde8;
    color: #111;
}
.currentType {
    background-color: #c0dde8;
    color: #111;
}
.results {
    display: none;
}
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // select list items in list
    $devisionProductTypes = $('#divisionMenus').children().children();

    $devisionProductTypes.each(function (index) {

        $(this).on('click', $(this), function() {
            $productType = $(this);
            $productTypeTitle = $productType.text();
            $otherProductTypes = $productType.not($(this));

            if (!$productType.hasClass('currentType')) {
                $productType.addClass('currentType');
                $otherProductTypes.removeClass('currentType');

                $('.results').show('fast').text('You have selected ' + $productTypeTitle);
            } else {
                $productType.removeClass('currentType');
                $otherProductTypes.removeClass('currentType');
            }

        });

    });

});
```

I used the same logic to iterate over some `div img` in order to toggle the size and it worked there. But not here. Am I missing something or am I approaching this all wrong.

Comment: well, for one, you don't need the .each, but that shouldn't make a difference. just delete everything between `$devisionProductTypes.` and `$(this).`, resulting in `$devisionProductTypes.on(...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're overcomplicating it, it sounds as simple as:

```
$('#divisionMenus li').on('click', function() {

  var $this = $(this);
  $this.toggleClass('currentType').siblings().removeClass('currentType');

  if ($this.hasClass('currentType')) {
    $('.results').show('fast').text('You have selected ' + $this.text());
  } else {
    $('.results').hide();
  }

});
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deifwud/83gk8/2/)

Comment: Don't spend a lot of time with JQuery, so I guess I was over complicating it by a lot! This works for me. Although I kept my variables because I will be accessing them for other parts of the code later (hopefully not to over complicate it any further. Thanks!  [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jremydeaton/S6mMF/5/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="divisionMenus">
    <ul>
        <li class='class1'>Type 01</li>
        <li class='class1'>Type 02</li>
        <li class='class1'>Type 03</li>
        <li class='class1'>Type 04</li>
    </ul>
    </div>

$('#divisionMenus .class1').click(function(){
$('.class1').removeClass('className');
$(this).addClass('className');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // select list items in list
    var $devisionProductTypes = $('#divisionMenus').children().children();

    $devisionProductTypes.on('click', $(this), function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.toggleClass('currentType').siblings('.currentType').removeClass('currentType');
        $('.results').show('fast').text('You have selected ' + $this.text());
    });

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wgkbx/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using to much code!

Here I cleaned up a little bit your code: http://jsfiddle.net/zxxza/

To remove currentClass. you can just select every elements with the class, then remove it and add the class to the clicked item. Just like that :

```
$('.currentType').removeClass('currentType');
$productType.addClass('currentType');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("li").click(function() {
//var $thisBtn = $(this);
if($("li").hasClass("btn-color")) {
    $("li").removeClass("btn-color");
    $(this).addClass("btn-color");
}
else {  
    $(this).addClass("btn-color");
}
});
```

Refer to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/vishwa26/VCUvF/) jsfiddle for the same.